# Understanding のではない and のではないか in the passage

Tags: translation, reading-comprehension

I was reading through Soumatome N1 Dokkai practice book when I encountered the passage below. Understanding the passage itself was not really difficult: ***the uncle did the prank***. But when it comes to answering the multiple choice question, I was stumped. Here is how I arrived at my answer:

1 その子供がまた今度いたずらをやったら許されない、と母は言った。

> This can't be true.

3 叔父はよくいたずらをするので、今回も叔父がやったと僕はおもった。

> This translates to the uncle did it.

2 今回のいたずらは、叔父さんがやったのではない、と僕は思った。

> I translated the part「叔父さんがやったのではない」as "the uncle did it"
>
> THIS IS WHY I GOT IT WRONG

What was going on my mind was that 「いいんじゃない」 conveys roughly the same meaning as「いいんだよね」and so I applied this logic. Apparently, it's wrong.

So, is it true that 「叔父さんがやったのではない」translates to "the uncle did not do it"? And if so, if I want to convey the fact that the uncle did it using the negative, just like 「いいんじゃん」, how should I write it?

[image]

Comment: You wrote やったこと multiple times, but in the actual question it's やったの. Is that interfering with your understanding?

Comment: Also, is there a double negative?

Comment: What was going on in my mind when I wrote it? Edited こと to の Thanks @Leebo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

叔父さんがやったのではない **exclusively** means "it is not the uncle that did it". The ～じゃん equivalent is 叔父さんがやったのではない**か**. Yes, it comes from question "Isn't it —?" then becomes to mean "How could it not —". And in formal saying you *cannot* drop the question particle か.

---

By the way, if written, the casual ～じゃない is certainly ambiguous even to Japanese, but their difference is clear in speech.

https://soundcloud.com/user-61112954/yattanjanai (created with [スズキクン](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/phrasing/index))

[image][image]

The first one (ない bears accent) is negative "did not", and the second "surely did" (=じゃん).

Comment: The second can also be じゃないか{HHLLL}, right?

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand what you mean. Because 〜叔父さんがやったのではない does not have the particle か, it can only mean that "the uncle did not do it". Now, if I add か to it, as in 叔父さんがやったのではない**か**と思った, does it become ambiguous and intonation dependent like ～じゃない

Comment: @rebuuilt Um, ambiguous to what? If you mean "whether uncle did --" and the "surely uncle did", yes, because it's a rhetorical question.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie That's the accent pattern after an unaccented phrase. I don't think it can appear with any verb conjugation, which always carries accent in the word IIRC. But indeed かんたんじゃない{LHHHHHLL}(か)

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Yes, ambiguous as to whether the speaker meant that the uncle did it or not. Thanks for that. It's clear now.

Comment: @rebuuilt I mean, when the speaker say 〜やったのではないか, it never means "did not". Only "did he?" (whether he did) or "I guess he did".

Comment: Right, @broccolifacemask-cloth. I think you made that clear when you said that it's a rhetorical question. It's really interesting how か can make all the difference (and how "if written, the casual ～じゃない is certainly ambiguous even to Japanese").